# Examples of ideals of $K$- algebras that do not have a basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I wanted to be more familiar with the idea of $K$-algebra etc and so I wanted to collect some examples for an ideal that do not have a basis.

Definition: A $K$-algebra is a ring who is also a $K$-vector space with the property that $K$ commutes with all the elements.

An (left) ideal, $I$, for a $K$-algebra, $A$, is a subset who is also an additive group of $A$ such that $ax\in I$ for all $a\in A$, $x\in I$.

The handful amount of examples I have for ideals of $K$-algebra all seem to have basis (basis over $K$, that is) and so I wanted to see more examples where a basis cannot possibly exist.

Thank you so much!

Comment: An ideal of a $K$-algebra is a vector space over $K$ and hence has a basis. What makes you think there should be examples that contradict this?

Comment: @RobArthan Ah right! Thank you! (I was only thinking because I didnt realise itself would be a subspace of $A$)